# QED sign does not always occur with package ntheorem

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I want to construct some theorem-type of environment by using package ntheorem.  I have edited the following source codes:

```
\documentclass[A4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem} 
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont }
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newtheorem{Def}{\bf Definition}

\begin{document}
\begin{Def}
    Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathbb{K}$ a field. Let $SL_n(\mathbb{K})$ denote the set of special linear group, that is
    $$SL_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}\mid |M|=1\}.$$
\end{Def}

 \begin{Def}
        Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathbb{K}$ a field. Let $SL_n(\mathbb{K})$ denote the set of special linear group, that is
        $SL_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}\mid |M|=1\}.$
\end{Def}

\begin{Def}
            Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathbb{K}$ a field. Let $SL_n(\mathbb{K})$ denote the set of special linear group, that is
            $$SL_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}\mid |M|=1\}.$$
        \vspace{-10ex}
        \begin{gather*}
        \end{gather*}
        \end{Def}
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

As you can see in Definition 1, the QED box dose not occur when the Def environment ends with the $$ ... $$.  But when I ends the whole Def environment with just $...$, as in Definition 2, the QED box does occur.

And I tried many ways. Finally, I have found some method to remedy this.  That is to modify the vertical space of QED box by the code:

```
\vspace{-10ex}
\begin{gather*}
\end{gather*}
```

added before the line of "end\Def". As in Definition 3, this method works. But it is very complex.

Is there any easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: If I leave an empty line after `special linear group, that is` and replace `$$` with `\[...\]`, I get the box.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  You should not use `$$...$$` for display mathematics in latex but rather `\[...\]`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/15925 .  With this change your example will work as expected.

Comment: I don't have to add whatever to obtain the qed symbol, but simply compile only twice. The only restriction in the doc is precisely there must be `no empty line` at the end — actually no empty line after an end of input in `paragraph mode`.

Comment: @HarishKumar -- leaving a blank line before a display is a bad thing.  aside from messing up the spacing around the display, it allows a page break, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I am aware of that. It was an observation, not a suggestion (that is why a comment) :-) Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `\[...\]`, or some other LaTeX math display environment, instead of the plain TeX `$$...$$`.  Many LaTeX packages rely on this, see also [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/15925).  In the case of `ntheorem` the marker will not get placed on displays with `$$...$$`.  Consider the following document, close to yours:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem} 

\theoremstyle{definition}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{Def}
  Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathbb{K}$ a field. Let
  $\mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K})$ denote the set of special linear group, that is
  \[
  \text{displaymath}\ \mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times
  n}\mid |M|=1\}
  \]
  or
  \[
  \text{displaymath}\ \mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times
  n}\mid |M|=1\}
  \]
  or
  $$ \text{dollars}\ \mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times
  n}\mid |M|=1\}$$
  or
  $$ \text{dollars}\ \mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times
  n}\mid |M|=1\}$$
  or
  \[
  \text{displaymath}\ \mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times
  n}\mid |M|=1\}
  \]
  or
  $$ \text{dollars}\ \mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times
  n}\mid |M|=1\}$$
  or
  $$ \text{dollars}\ \mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{K}):=\{M\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}\mid |M|=1\}.$$
\end{Def}


\end{document}
```

Examining the `aux` file we find that `ntheorem` outputs the line

```
\global\def\markiDefiii{\ensuremath {\Box }}
```

which comes from the third `\[...\]` pair, corresponding the roman numeral `iii`.  The `$$...$$` do not get counted and on the next run `ntheorem` places the qed mark at the end of the third `\[...\]` display:

[image: Sample output]

Note also you definition of the `Def` environment is bad.  Font formatting should not be put in the label, instead you should use

```
\theoremheadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

Perhaps the `amsthm` option was causing problems with setting these fonts, it is deprecated in the `ntheorem` documentation, however if you do use then there is a built in `definition` theoremstyle which I have used above.